# what is correct syntax for a LWC getpicklistvalues and getobjectinfo for custom objects and custom fields

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to get a picklist values into a LWC. I do not see the syntax for custom objects. and get error [FRESHDESK__FRESHDESK_TICKET_OBJECT__C_OBJECT is not defined]

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: FRESHDESK__FRESHDESK_TICKET_OBJECT__C_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', // Default record type Id
        fieldApiName: FD_GROUP__c_FIELD
    })
```

the api name for industry is FD_GROUP__c
the api name for the object is FRESHDESK__FRESHDESK_TICKET_OBJECT__C

Answer (score 1):

It's whatever you want to call it:

```
// Here, I call it FRESHDESK__FRESHDESK_TICKET_OBJECT__C, but you can use whatever you like.
import FRESHDESK__FRESHDESK_TICKET_OBJECT__C from '@salesforce/schema/Freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c';
```

...

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: FRESHDESK__FRESHDESK_TICKET_OBJECT__C }) objectInfo;
```

You just need to remember that you must import the token to use the token-style syntax. You can alternatively use a string:

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: 'Freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c }) objectInfo;
```

Remember that, for objects with a namespace, you must also include that in your import statement.

Comment: @sfdxfox thanks. Got it to work. i just named my field and then called it later.